# Using the same predicates for two criteria queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I want to run a pair of queries using the same array of `Predicate`: one to count the records, one to get a certain page of records. This seems like a pretty normal use case, to me, so there must be a good way to do it, but I have yet to find it.

So this is the part that fetches entities:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
EntityType<ENTITY> entityType = entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(FooEntity.class);
CriteriaQuery<FooEntity> entityQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(FooEntity.class);
Root<FooEntity> entityRoot = entityQuery.from(FooEntity.class);

// Use the criteria builder, root, and type to create some predicates.
Predicate[] predicates = createPredicates(criteriaBuilder, entityRoot, entityType );

// Fetch the entities.
entityQuery.select(entityRoot);
entityQuery.where(predicates);
List<FooEntity> entities = entityManager.createQuery(entityQuery)
    .setFirstResult(0) // Just get the first page
    .setMaxResults(50)
    .getResultList();
```

This works. We get what we desire, predicates are correct etc.

However, creating another query to determine the count using the same predicates fails. I've tried two different ways:

(1) Re-using the `Root`:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(entityRoot));
countQuery.where(predicates);
long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

This doesn't work and gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No criteria query roots were specified`. Odd, since I clearly specified the `Root`, but perhaps I can't re-use a `Root` that was created from a different `CriteriaQuery`? Fine, let's create one from the same `CriteriaQuery`...

(2) Creating a new `Root`:

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(countQuery.from(FooEntity.class));
countQuery.where(predicates);
long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Now we get a different error: `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.fooProperty' [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.foo.FooEntity as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias1.fooProperty = :param0 )]`

Looking at the HQL that was created, it appears that the "from" clause sets a `generatedAlias0`, but all the stuff in the "where" clause references `generatedAlias1`. My guess is because the array of `Predicate` was built using a different `Root` than was used in the `CriteriaQuery<Long>`.

So, if it doesn't work either way, how would I re-use the same array of `Predicate`? Do I really have to re-create all of them with the second `Root`? That seems super excessive to me, especially since they're both `Root<FooEntity>`. I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: just specify root like you do `ntityQuery.from(FooEntity.class);`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My option (1) is the same thing, but just for posterity, I tried creating a new root from the entity query: `countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(entityQuery.from(FooEntity.class)));`

... but as expected, it yielded the same error ("No criteria query roots were specified").

Answer (score 5):

You should use the same alias for the both Root elements, example:

```
Root<FooEntity> entityRoot = entityQuery.from(FooEntity.class);
entityRoot.alias("alias1") // Property alias

Predicate[] predicates = createPredicates(criteriaBuilder, entityRoot, entityType );

// Fetch the entities.
entityQuery.select(entityRoot);
entityQuery.where(predicates);
List<FooEntity> entities = entityManager.createQuery(entityQuery)
    .setFirstResult(0)
    .setMaxResults(50)
    .getResultList();


CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<FooEntity> newRoot = countQuery.from(FooEntity.class);
newRoot.alias("alias1"); // Same property alias

countQuery.select(builder.count(newRoot));
countQuery.where(predicates);
Long count = em.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

This way JPA understands and query using the same restrictions

Comment: This should be the acceptable answer. I used this and it worked. If you have joins, you need to create new joins from the new roots also setting the aliases to match.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new `Root`, `CriteriaQuery` and `CriteriaBuiler` for every query.

If you use **Spring**, [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) can be opted for making `Predicate` reusable. Otherwise you can create your own `Specification` functional interface like this

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Specification<T> {
    Predicate toPredicate(
          Root<T> root, 
          CriteriaQuery<?> query, 
          CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder);
}
```

Usage:

```
public Specification<FooEntity> createSpecification(YourParameters parameters) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Predicate fullPredicate;

        // create predicates using parameters, root, query, criteriaBuilder 
        // and concatenate them into one: fullPredicate = predicate.and(anotherPredicate);

        return fullPredicate;
    };
}
```

And then you can get predicate for every query this way

```
Predicate predicate = createSpecification(parameters)
    .toPredicate(entityRoot, entityQuery, criteriaBuilder);
```

The best approach is to create utility class with separated methods for every specification and combine them you need using `Specification.and` method

Answer (score 1):

As an option, it is possible to get entities and count by using a single CriteriaQuery with multiselect. In this way we will reuse the same set of predicates as well. For example:

```
@Getter
class MultiselectBox {
    long count;
    Entity entity;

    MultiselectBox(long c) { count = c; }        
    MultiselectBox(Entity e) {  entity = e; }
}    

class EntityDao {
    EntityManager em;
    
    Page<Entity> search(Filter filter, Pageable pageRequest) {
        var cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var cq = cb.createQuery(MultiselectBox.class);
        var root = cq.from(Entity.class);
        
        cq.multiselect(root).where(buildPredicates(filter));
        cq.orderBy(buildSort(pageRequest.getSort()));
        
        var tq = em.createQuery(cq);
        tq.setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());
        tq.setFirstResult(pageRequest.getPageSize());
        var results = tq.getResultList().stream()
                .map(MultiselectBox::getEntity).toList();
        
        long count;
        if (results.size() < pageRequest.getPageSize()) {
            count = results.size();
        } else {
            cq.orderBy(Collections.emptyList());
            cq.multiselect(cb.count(root));
            count = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult().getCount();
        }
        
        return new PageImpl<>(results, pageRequest, count);
    }
}
```

Base on this [discussion](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-6-1-6-using-jakarta-criteria-and-count-query-getting-exception-in-count-query-execution-if-count-query-contains-where-predicate/7455/2) it is impossible to reuse predicate between different queries at least in Hibernate 6.